# MVC Telerik grid - Cancel update AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

This is my Telerik grid code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model).Name("DistributionGrid").DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add("DistributionID")).
                                                ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar
                      .Template(@<text>
                                @{ 
                                    <b>Distribution</b>
                                    <ul class='ul-bulk-menu'>
                                        <li><button id='newDistribution' class='t-button t-button-icon' title='New Distribution'><span>Add Distribution</span></button></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  }

                            </text>))

                                        .Columns(c =>
                                        {
                                            c.Command(command =>
                                            {
                                                command.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Edit Distribution"});
                                                command.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Delete Distribution" });
                                            }).Width(100);

                                            c.Bound(o => o.DistTo);
                                            c.Bound(o => o.DistCC);

                                        })

                                        .Scrollable(o => o.Height(440))
                                        .Resizable(o => o.Columns(true))
                                        .Reorderable(o => o.Columns(true))

                                        .DataBinding(o => o.Ajax()
                                            .Select("SelectDist", "Mail")
                                            .Update("UpdateDist", "Mail")
                                            .Delete("DeleteDist", "Mail")
                                            )

                                        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InForm))
                                        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnCommand("Grid_OnRequestStart"))
                                    ) 
</div>
```

I have a jQuery interrupted the "update" function using jQuery using the following code:

```
function Grid_OnRequestStart(e) {
    if (e.name == "update") {
        alert(e.dataItem.DistTo + " - " + $("#DistTo").val());
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            alert("Distribution was updated!");
        }
        else {
        // Here I want to cancel the update request
        }
    }
}
```

In the "else" option I want to cancel the AJAX "update" request.

Is it possible?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this line of code which should cancel the ajax request.

```
function Grid_OnRequestStart(e) {
    if (e.name == "update") {
        alert(e.dataItem.DistTo + " - " + $("#DistTo").val());
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            alert("Distribution was updated!");
        }
        else {
            e.set_enableAjax(false); // cancel ajax request
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
According to Telerik documentation, here's the description for `requestStart` event

> The event handler function context (available via the this keyword)
>   will be set to the data source instance.
>
> It is possible to prevent the remote request. To achieve this, execute
>   e.preventDefault() in the handler function.
>
> This event can be prevented only for **read** requests.

This was also mentioned in other posts in the forum, see the attached links below.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-datasource-read-request-to-server#70iyzKcdAEibUPEpGJL_hw

http://www.telerik.com/forums/cancel-ongoing-ajax-filter-request-and-start-new-one#tQxdD9YFpESlQK_zrVC4jg

Perhaps not entirely impossible but will definitely require some extra work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
Actually, using this line I got the following error:
"VM466:43 Uncaught TypeError: e.set_enableAjax is not a function".
But it stopped the AJAX function from being executed.

Comment: @Lena Hmm, ok, could you try `set_cancel(true);` method?

Comment: Error again: "Uncaught ReferenceError: set_cancel is not defined"